# unable to generate dynamic listview through JQuery Mobile with JSON response?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, cordova

Here is my Json response format :-

```
{"Value":[{"ID":"1","productID":"10","subsID":"9","MinPrice":"500","MaxPrice":"50000","Subs":"xyz100"}]}
```

Here is my .js code :-

```
function productURL(url) {
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(msg) {
            var respPrice = msg.Value;
            $.each(respPrice, function(index, value) {
                if(value.VarietyID == 0) {
                    alert('No product subs list found');
                } else {

                    subsId = value.subsID;
                    substance = value.subs;
                    minPrice = value.MinPrice;
                    maxPrice = value.MaxPrice;
                    respPrice += '<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-e">' + substance + minPrice + '-' + maxPrice + '</li>';
                    };

                    }           
                });
             $('#productList').append(respPrice).listview('refresh');

                },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
                alert('Error Occoured');
            }
        });
}
```

Whats modifications do i need to do to get the proper generation of listview ? Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Put var respPrice = ""; `not` var respPrice = msg.Value;.  What s the position of 'Alumimi ' in list. Is it first data or last data in list?

Comment: It is at the last resembles xyz100 in the response and its Alumini1008 and the rest are minPrice and maxPrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you do this way??

```
$.each(respPrice.Value, function(index, value) {
      if(respPrice.VarietyID == 0) {
         alert('No product subs list found');
      } else {

       subsId = value.subsID;
       substance = value.Subs;
       minPrice = value.MinPrice;
       maxPrice = value.MaxPrice;       
       $respPrice = '<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-e">' + substance + minPrice + '-' + maxPrice + '</li>';

       // append here
       $('#productList').append($respPrice);
     }               
 });

 // and when all done, after $.each() refresh the listview
 $('#productList').listview('refresh');
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/19/

Comment: you have changed the response format. I have a different json Response format. Plz look at the format at the top in my question it includes an "Value:" in the format.

Comment: when i tried ur solution with my response format in the jsfiddle it doesn't work man. Any other way to do it..

Comment: and when i created a variable and stored the "Value" in that, then i ended up with the same mess.

Comment: Man u did the trick...thanks a lot...however will you plz help me regarding the allignment of minPrice and maxPrice to be appear after certain gap after substance name...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
success : function(msg) {
            var respPrice = "";
            $.each(respPrice, function(index, value) {
                if(value.VarietyID == 0) {
                    alert('No product subs list found');
                } else {

                    subsId = value.subsID;
                    substance = value.subs;
                    minPrice = value.MinPrice;
                    maxPrice = value.MaxPrice;
                    respPrice += '<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-e">' + substance + minPrice + '-' + maxPrice + '</li>';
                    }

                    } 
 $('#productList').append(respPrice).listview('refresh');          
                });


                },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
                alert('Error Occoured');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thnx for ur early response geet. i have tried ur solution bt i get an error in logcat like :-  W/InputManagerService(73): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@461b4f18   and the application doesn't give any response.