# Jquery mobile - Click button to add to UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i am trying to build an application that when the user enters text into a textbox on a jquery based mobile app and clicks save it adds it to the list on the screen

so by default i won't have a list, but as the user adds an item the list should be created or if the list already exists, the new item added as a new list item.

in terms of saving it i will work on that after, for the time being i just want to dynamically append to a ul in jqm on the screen

Can someone assist with code that may help with this. it is giving me an item added saying "item undefined" however numslist is my list and txtbox is the textbox so im not sure where i am going wrong

thanks

```
<script>
    var $txtbox = $("#txtbox").val();
      var count = 0;
      $("#main").live("pagecreate", function(event) {
        $("#numlist").listview({create: function(event, ui) {
          $("#addBtn").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
            var str = "<li><a href='#'>Item " + ($txtbox) + "</a></li>";
            $("#numlist").append(str);
            $("#numlist").listview("refresh");
          });
          $("#removeBtn").bind("click", function(event, ui) {
           // if (--count < 0) {
             // count = 0;
             // return;
           // }
            $("#numlist").find("li").remove();
            $("#numlist").listview("refresh");
          });
        }});
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606013/unable-to-generate-dynamic-listview-through-jquery-mobile-with-json-response/18606279#18606279

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use localstorage, that way you won't need to code extra functions that save/store data.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var $lst = $('#productList');
$("#btnID").on("click",function() {    
    var $txtBox = $("#txtBox");
    var $li = $('<li/>').html($txtBox.val());           
    $lst.append($li).listview('refresh'); 
    $txtBox.val("");
 });
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/21/

Comment: for some reason that isn't working and i don't know why. I've updated the code above with what i have, but i tried yours by itself and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, something similar to the following should work for you:

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {
    var ul = $('#ul_id').length > 0 ? $('#ul_id') : $('<ul />', { id: 'ul_id'}).appendTo('#parent');
    $('<li />').text($('#textbox').val()).appendTo(ul);
});
```

The first line in the event will check if the  element exists, if it does, it returns that, otherwise, creates a new  and appends to the specified parent element. Then, it appends a  to the  with the text from the textbox.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JJgZ3/2/)